# Does the pointwise identity $\frac{e^{tf}-1}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f$ also hold with respect to the supremum norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, exponential-function

Let $f\in C(\mathbb R^d;\mathbb C)$ and $g\in C_b(\mathbb R^d;\mathbb C)$. Are we able to show that $$\frac{e^{tf}g-g}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}fg\tag1$$ with respect to the supremum norm on $C_b\mathbb R^d;\mathbb C)$?

Since $$\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{e^{tc}-1}t=\left.\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}e^{tc}\right|_{t=0}=c\tag2,$$ $(1)$ obviously holds pointwisely.

And since the supremum norm is clearly submultiplicative, it should be sufficient to show $$\left\|\frac{e^{tf}-1}t-f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{t\to0+}0\tag3.$$

Are we able to show this?

*Remark*: In my application, I know that $|f(x)|\le c(1+|x|^2)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$ for some $c\ge0$. So, if necessary, feel free to assume this.

*Remark 2*: What I'm trying to understand is the equation after (6.5) in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301841350_An_Introduction_to_L%27evy_and_Feller_Processes_Advanced_Courses_in_Mathematics_-_CRM_Barcelona_2014).

Comment: Major typo or something here...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $f$ should only be continuous and there was a $g$ missing at the right-hand side of $(1)$, but I'm not sure whether this is the typo you're meaning. Could you clarify?

Comment: Shouldn't the convergence be in $L^1$ for your Remark 2? But I doubt that $e^{tf}g$ is even integrable...the fourier transform of a compactly supported function cannot decay exponentially.

Comment: (yes, that's the problem I had with the first version) If $t,f>0$ then $\frac{e^{tf}-1}t-f>\frac12tf^2$. Or something like that...

Comment: @unwissen No, the generator considered in the paper is a generator of an operator on a closed subspace of $C_b(\mathbb R^d)$ equipped with the supremum norm. So, the convergence has to be understood with respect to the supremum norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is a function of polynomial growth, then $(e^{tf(x)}-1)/t$ converges to $f(x)$ uniformly on compact sets of $x$, but it does not need to converge uniformly as $t\to 0$. Multiplying by a function $g(x)$ could in principle help the convergence, but $g(x)$ would have to decrease to $0$ very fast. For example, if $|f(x)|=O(|x|^2)$ as $|x|\to\infty$, then $g(x)$ should decay even faster than $e^{-|x|^2}$, otherwise for any fixed $t$, we could make the expression
$$\frac{e^{tf(x)}g(x)-g(x)}{t}$$
have size comparable to $1$ for $x$ very large.

In the document you linked to, $g(x)$ is a Schwartz function, so we know that $g(x)$ does decay faster than any fixed polynomial, which seems useful, but because your $f(x)$ grows like a polynomial, $g(x)$ being Schwartz isn't enough to conclude that the convergence you are aiming for is uniform, because decaying faster than any fixed polynomial is not the same as decaying faster than $\exp(-|\text{polynomial}|)$.

Now I'll switch to the notation used in the document you linked to. Presumably, you are interested in the question about uniform convergence because you want to take the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{\widehat{P_tf}-\widehat f}{t}$ and argue that as $t\to 0$, by uniform convergence, this would converge to $\mathscr F^{-1}(-\psi \widehat f)$. Equivalently, you want to exchange the derivative and the integral in
\begin{align*}
\int e^{ix\cdot\xi}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_{t=0}\widehat{P_tf}(\xi)\,d\xi &= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\int e^{ix\cdot\xi}\widehat{P_tf}(\xi)\,d\xi
\end{align*}
Fortunately, you don't need uniform convergence in order to justify this exchange. Using "the differentiation lemma for parameter-dependent integrals" that the author mentions is probably all you need, though I admit I don't have either of the given references on hand. Here is one formulation that works for what you need:

> **Differentating under the integral sign.** Suppose that $F(x,t)$ is integrable as a function of $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for each value of $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and differentiable as a function of $t$ for each value of $x$.  Assume also that
> $$\bigg| \frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(x,t) \bigg| \le G(x),$$
> for all $x,t$, where $G(x)$ is an integrable function of $x$.  Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(x,t)$ is integrable as a function of $x$ for each $t$ and
> $$\frac{d}{dt} \int F(x,t)\, dx = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(x,t)\,dx.$$

The proof is by the dominated convergence theorem, which is more flexible than the result that allows you to exchange limits and integrals under the condition of uniform convergence, as this problem you're having shows.

I will leave the proof of this formulation up to you, but in order to apply it, all we need to verify is that $-e^{ix\cdot\xi}\psi(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi)$ is bounded by an integrable function of $\xi$. Since $f$ is Schwartz, $\widehat f$ is Schwartz too, so since $\psi$ only has fixed polynomial growth and $|e^{ix\cdot \xi}| = 1$, $|\!-\!e^{ix\cdot\xi}\psi(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi)|\le C(1+|\xi|)^{-100d}$, where $d$ is the dimension of the ambient space and $C$ is some possibly large but fixed constant. The function $C(1+|\xi|)^{-100d}$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^d$, so we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Presumably, you are interested in the question about uniform convergence because you want to take the inverse Fourier transform* ... Not exactly. We don't need the uniform convergence to apply the inverse Fourier transform (and we don't need differentiation under the integral sign either). The problem is that the resulting convergence of $\frac{P_tf-f}t$ has to be uniform (see my comment on the generator below the question).

Comment: Regarding your worries about $g$ (called $f$ in the paper) only being a Schwarz function: Note that this is not the assumption in the paper; they assume that $g$ (i.e. $f$) is $C_c^\infty$. This should eliminate the problem.

Comment: So, the guideline should be to use differentiation under the integral sign to show that $\frac{P_tf-f}t\to g$ ($g=\mathcal F^{-1}(-\psi\hat f)$ as in the paper) **pointwisely** and then show that this convergence is even uniform. I guess for the latter we need that $f$ has compact support. Do you agree?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: It looks like $f$ from the paper is $C_c^\infty$, but this only guarantees that $\widehat f$ is Schwartz, so you still can't guarantee that $(\widehat{P_tf}-\widehat f)/t$ converges uniformly by my initial remarks in my answer. It looks like in Definition 5.3, we require uniform convergence, but actually since every Lévy process is also a Feller process (Lemma 4.8 and Definition 5.1), you can get away with establishing pointwise convergence (Theorem 5.12), as this proof does.

Comment: It's almost clear to me how we obtain the pointwise convergence by differentiation under the integral sign. However, there are two issues which I'm not able to resolve. I've accept this answer and asked a separate question for these remaining issues. Please take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4272094/47771.

Comment: Regarding your latest comment: In order to apply $(Theorem 5.12)$, we need that $(P_t)$ is a Feller semigroup. Is that the case? It's clear to me that, by the dominated convergence theorem, $(P_tg)(x)\to 0$ as $\|x\|\to\infty$ for every $g\in C_0(\mathbb R^d)$, but is this enough to ensure $P_tg\in C_0(\mathbb R^d)$? (My definition of $C_0(\mathbb R^d)$ is that $g\in C_0(\mathbb R^d)$ if $\{|g|\ge\varepsilon\}$ is compact for all $\varepsilon>0$. This clearly implies $g(x)\to0$ as $\|x\|\to\infty$, but I don't know whether this condition is even sufficient for $g\in C_0(\mathbb R^d)$.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d: By assumption, $P_t$ is a Lévy process, so in particular it is a Feller process by Lemma 4.8. So you can apply Theorem 5.12.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you. Do you know how we can resolve the mentioned issues to obtain the pointwise convergence?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your remark as $f$ being a bounded function already implies the bound $\vert f(x) \vert \leq c(1 + \vert x \vert^2)$ with $c = \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$.

In spite of that, we have
$$
\frac{e^{t f(x)} - 1}{t} = f(x) \, e^{\theta f(x)}
$$ for a $\theta \in (0, t)$ by the Mean Value Theorem.

Therefore,
$$
\left\vert \frac{e^{t f(x)} - 1}{t} - f(x) \right\vert
= \vert f(x) \vert \, \vert e^{\theta f(x)} - 1 \vert
\, \leq \, \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} (e^{\vert\theta f(x) \vert} - 1)
\, \leq \, \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}(e^{t \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}} - 1),
$$ where the last term goes to zero as $t \to 0$, uniformly in $x$.

Comment: In your proof you are assuming that $\|f\|_{\infty}<+\infty$, that is the function is uniformely bounded. This is way stronger than the hypothesis you actually have.

Comment: I'm sorry, $f$ should only be continuous; not bounded.

Comment: $(3)$ does not hold in general. If $g$ has compact support or if $f$ is bounded, then the convergence in $(1)$ is uniform.

Comment: @ecrin this is because the hypothesis was like this and the statement (3) is never true for unbounded $f$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can't have a uniform convergence, even adding the bound: let $f(x)=x$, which respect $|f(x)|\le (1+x^2)$, and $g=1$, which is bounded, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{e^{tx}-1}{t}\to+\infty && x\to+\infty,
\end{align*}
that contradicts the fact that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a $g$ missing at the right-hand side of $(1)$.

Comment: Regarding the uniform convergence: What I'm trying to understand is the equation after (6.5) in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301841350_An_Introduction_to_L%27evy_and_Feller_Processes_Advanced_Courses_in_Mathematics_-_CRM_Barcelona_2014). Maybe I'm missing an additional assumption?

Comment: You are missing the definition of Schwartz function (see footnote 1, page 36 of the paper).
This is a way stronger assumption than what you stated above